# Save image from http response with sockets in C and Lua

Tags: c, http, ssl, lua, png

I made a C function that sends a http request over https and now I need to grab the image retrieved with that request with Lua. 
But when I remove the header and save the body the image is not a valid one.

When the file requested is text nothing wrong happens.

This is the function to send the http request

```
static char* receive(BIO *bio, int chunksize) {
    int  readbytes, count = 1;
    char tmp[chunksize], *buf = NULL;

    buf = (char *) malloc(chunksize * sizeof(char));
    buf[0] = '\0';
    while(1) {
        readbytes = BIO_read(bio, tmp, chunksize - 1); 
        if(readbytes <= 0) break;
        tmp[readbytes] = '\0';

        buf = (char *) realloc(buf, chunksize * sizeof(char) * count);

        strncat(buf, tmp, strlen(tmp));

        count++;
    }
    return buf;
}

static int ssl_get(const char *host, const char *port, const char *request, char **response, const int datasize, const int hostsize) {
    char host_port[hostsize];
    int host_size;

    /* ssl */
    BIO *bio;
    SSL *ssl;
    SSL_CTX *ctx;

    /* init ssl lib */
    SSL_library_init();
    ERR_load_BIO_strings();
    OpenSSL_add_all_algorithms();

    /* set up ssl context */
    ctx = SSL_CTX_new(SSLv23_client_method());

    /* set up connection */
    bio = BIO_new_ssl_connect(ctx);
    BIO_get_ssl(bio, &ssl);
    SSL_set_mode(ssl, SSL_MODE_AUTO_RETRY);

    /* create connection */
    /* host and port on the form of <host>:<port> */
    strncpy(host_port, host, strlen(host));
    host_size = strlen(host);
    host_port[host_size] = ':';
    host_port[host_size + 1] = '\0';
    strncat(host_port, port, strlen(port));


    BIO_set_conn_hostname(bio, host_port);

    if (BIO_do_connect(bio) <= 0) {
        //fprintf(stderr, "Error attempting to connect\n");
        //ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);
        BIO_free_all(bio);
        SSL_CTX_free(ctx);
        return -2;
    }

    /* Send request */
    BIO_write(bio, request, strlen(request));

    /* read response */
    (*response) = receive(bio, datasize);


    BIO_free_all(bio);
    SSL_CTX_free(ctx);

    return 0;
}
```

This is the request

```
GET host.org/path/to/image.png HTTP/1.0\r\n\r\n
```

and this is the first part of what I receive

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx/1.10.2
Date: Sun, 19 Feb 2017 20:41:58 GMT
Content-Type: image/png
Content-Length: 88746
Last-Modified: Thu, 10 Nov 2016 00:30:48 GMT
Connection: close
ETag: "5823bfb8-15aaa"
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=15768000
Accept-Ranges: bytes

PNG

Ü­¢
;«&_éÓöñ}®¸Ú6ËpkÕ²®ÚÃz·f­KÑÙfuY#¸   #åÂj½põ¿§Lá[ÉjùÝ5Â®çsã9ûIåå>%¸°Ôà`Pé§x×|QWqXá²!jØZOö­ºÿýõÍº¡Ws¦04ÜGM9¦¡FÄ¡¶|Ú*)Ëº9Émß6>8­ö»I#/jI®ÛfËþ.ã50Ï­ïð.éÑ¦ÚAíõX
```

in contrast with the image downloaded with the browser

```
PNG

���
IHDR��U��m���Þ¡Z²���sRGB�®Îé���gAMA��±üa��� pHYs��Ä��Ä+���bKGD�ÿ�ÿ�ÿ ½§��ÿIDATx^ìüEÙÇ}­¼( Ò;IÐ;üCïI`�¥ªüc{M@"*JUD
 "EPÐ¤'T!@hI�é  `Ë;ß¹Û¹½Ù½Ý»Ý»½»çûù<Éý÷övgggwç·Ï3Ï,´@£AAA¦x_ð¿   Ð"ªAAAZ@D   B¨AAAhU   - ¢JAA¡DT       ´*AAAQ%  Ð^Q5ïj¡ªµg¨yÁ÷!óÔ#¾o¾r´Z¶äßO7NM>çÎôqýÛOuïlc\ý^ÒãôqÁ6¬y¶U6êÊdÁñ×ÅuFç{Û)ª­z
uö_EÜ÷ÜãHs~Ò!¹\½Ò²Õ]/Ñç7®ÜyO{ÛM~×g§Îkñõ­>òì¹íÆ$·Î·ÝrU03øÛaæ5THôfº§ëaÔäàÏ>ÅÝød5¥íuáµ�®70|hðIènjëÅ_CmG®&éÁ¶ 8tëù+w¿µW©Z<î~­ÓÞ¢FTÍ;ã@åÓS.G¹jt?cZ°@Ûñú¯2ÑjÙü¿>n9E2]Õh*Íd¯ª*®î³ã¼9³OjâÜJyf/WK£¨¶^ü5Ô~Ês´ûvº
```

---

All the code

[Complete C library](http://pastebin.com/6p2sGfmY)

[Aux Lua module](http://pastebin.com/504SLaEQ)

Lua Script

```
#!/usr/bin/lua

sslrequest = require "sslrequest"
parse = require "parse"

local protocol_, host, port, request = parse.spliturl("https://host.fake/path/to/image.png")
local res = sslrequest.ssl_get(host, port, "GET " .. request .. " HTTP/1.0\r\n\r\n", 1024, 100)
local _, body = separate_http(res)

local f = assert(io.open("img.png", "wb"))
f:write(body)
f:close()
```

I don't know what I am missing

EDIT:
Image files in Hex

Image downloaded with the browser

```
00000000: 8950 4e47 0d0a 1a0a 0000 000d 4948 4452  .PNG........IHDR
00000010: 0000 0355 0000 026d 0806 0000 00de a15a  ...U...m.......Z
00000020: b200 0000 0173 5247 4200 aece 1ce9 0000  .....sRGB.......
00000030: 0004 6741 4d41 0000 b18f 0bfc 6105 0000  ..gAMA......a...
00000040: 0009 7048 5973 0000 0ec4 0000 0ec4 0195  ..pHYs..........
00000050: 2b0e 1b00 0000 0662 4b47 4400 ff00 ff00  +......bKGD.....
00000060: ffa0 bda7 9300 00ff 8049 4441 5478 5eec  .........IDATx^.
00000070: 9d07 fc1c 45d9 c707 7dad bc28 20d2 3b49  ....E...}..( .;I
00000080: 90d0 3bfc 43ef 4904 8260 00a5 aafc 637b  ..;.C.I..`....c{
00000090: 4d40 9022 2a4a 5544 820d 120b 2022 4581  M@."*JUD.... "E.
000000a0: 5092 d0a4 2754 2140 6849 00e9 108a 2020  P...'T!@hI....  
000000b0: 60cb 3bdf b99d dbb9 bdd9 bddd bbdd bbbd  `.;.............
000000c0: bbe7 fbf9 3cc9 fdf7 f676 6767 6777 e7b7  ....<....vgggw..
000000d0: cf33 cf2c b440 a304 4110 0441 1004 4110  .3.,.@..A..A..A.
000000e0: 84a6 785f f0bf 2008 8220 0882 2008 82d0  ..x_.. .. .. ...
000000f0: 0422 aa04 4110 0441 1004 4110 5a40 4495  ."..A..A..A.Z@D.
00000100: 2008 8220 0882 2008 420b 88a8 1204 4110   .. .. .B.....A.
00000110: 0441 1004 4168 0111 5582 2008 8220 0882  .A..Ah..U. .. ..
00000120: 2008 2d20 a24a 1004 4110 0441 1004 a105   .- .J..A..A....
00000130: 4454 0982 2008 8220 0882 20b4 8088 2a41  DT.. .. .. ...*A
00000140: 1004 4110 0441 1084 1610 5125 0882 2008  ..A..A....Q%.. .
00000150: 8220 0882 d002 5e51 35ef 8c11 6aa1 8516  . ....^Q5...j...
00000160: aab5 1167 a879 c1f7 21f3 d419 2392 be6f  ...g.y..!...#..o
00000170: 17be 72b4 5ab6 e4df 4f1f 374e 4d0f 3ee7  ..r.Z...O.7NM.>.
00000180: cef4 7195 fd1a 8bdb 4f1e 75ef 6c63 5cfd  ..q.....O.u.lc\.
00000190: 5ed2 1ee3 f471 c136 ac79 b655 36ea ca9c  ^....q.6.y.U6...
000001a0: 64c1 f184 d7c5 0875 46e7 1a7b db29 aaad  d......uF..{.)..
000001b0: 177a 0d75 80f6 5f07 45dc f7dc e348 737e  .z.u.._.E....Hs~
000001c0: d296 21b9 5cbd d216 b2d5 5d2f d19b e737  ..!.\.....]/...7
000001d0: aedc 791f 4f7b db4d 7ed7 67a7 ce6b f1f5  ..y.O{.M~.g..k..
000001e0: 95ad 3ef2 ec1b 14b9 edc6 241f b78f ceb7  ..>.......$.....
000001f0: dd72 1111 5595 020f 9d30 33f8 db61 e604  .r..U....03..a..
00000200: 3554 1f48 17f4 970b 66ba 1aa7 eb61 d4e4  5T.H....f....a..
00000210: e0cf 0298 3ec5 ddf8 6435 a5ed 759e e118  ....>...d5..u...
00000220: b500 8cae 3730 7c68 f049 e86e 8a6a ebc5  ....70|h.I.n.j..
00000230: 5f43 6d47 ae83 26e9 c1b6 2038 74eb f98d  _CmG..&... 8t...
00000240: 2b77 bfb5 57a9 875a 8a3c ee7e add3 dea2  +w..W..Z.<.~....
00000250: 4654 cd3b e340 e5d3 532e 9347 b96a 7488  FT.;.@..S..G.jt.
00000260: 1a3f 6381 5ab0 40db 8cf1 faaf 32d1 6ad9  .?c.Z.@.....2.j.
00000270: fcbf 9f3e 6e94 9639 4532 5dd5 682a cd64  ...>n..9E2].h*.d
00000280: afaa 2aae eeb3 1ce3 bc39 b383 4f03 6ae2  ..*......9..O.j.
00000290: dc4a 7966 8c2f 574b 109a a3a8 b65e fc35  .Jyf./WK.....^.5
000002a0: d47e ca73 1db4 fb9e 9c76 7f9d ba9f 0aed  .~.s.....v......
000002b0: a1b7 ce6f 5cb9 7bb7 bd66 3b7f bd7f ddb6  ...o\.{..f;.....
000002c0: bf3d 97a3 4ed3 decf 8538 6a44 d5dc 87ad  .=..N....8jD....
000002d0: a20a 3b06 159b ab26 0e04 5fe9 d31e f6f1  ..;....&.._.....
000002e0: 7dae b88a da36 cb70 6bd5 84b2 859e aeda  }....6.pk.......
000002f0: 10c3 7ab7 66ad 4bd1 d966 7559 231a b809  ..z.f.K..fuY#...
00000300: 23e5 c26a bd70 f5bf a74c e15b 84c9 6a94  #..j.p...L.[..j.
00000310: f9dd 0835 c2ae e773 e339 fb49 e5e5 9b3e  ...5...s.9.I...>
```

Image downloaded with the program

```
00000000: 8950 4e47 0d0a 1a0a 36cb 706b d584 b285  .PNG....6.pk....
00000010: 9eae da10 c37a b766 ad4b d1d9 6675 5923  .....z.f.K..fuY#
00000020: 1ab8 0923 e5c2 6abd 70f5 bfa7 4ce1 5b84  ...#..j.p...L.[.
00000030: c96a 94f9 dd08 35c2 aee7 73e3 39fb 49e5  .j....5...s.9.I.
00000040: e59b 3e25 b8b0 06d4 e060 50e9 93a7 788e  ..>%.....`P...x.
00000050: d77f 7c51 5771 588f e1b2 9021 6ad8 5a95  ..|QWqX....!j.Z.
00000060: 4ff6 adba ff18 fdf5 cdba a157 73a6 9a30  O..........Ws..0
00000070: 34dc 474d 39a6 9fa1 46c4 94a1 b67c da12  4.GM9...F....|..
00000080: 2a29 cbba 8d18 39c9 6ddf 9136 3e38 adf6  *)....9.m..6>8..
00000090: bb49 2383 2f6a 49ae db90 66cb 1dfe 2ee3  .I#./jI...f.....
000000a0: 3530 cfad ef8a 8df0 142e e91c d1a6 93da  50..............
000000b0: 41ed f51b 580a 773c c714 b7dd 52b6 9914  A...X.w<....R...
000000c0: 75c9 3ee2 ae03 1f45 1c67 48c2 7dcf 732c  u.>....E.gH.}.s,
000000d0: 49e5 ac10 6977 75e7 b8c1 7db6 4a07 eea7  I...iwu...}.J...
000000e0: 298f b7e6 7ce8 ef6a eb3d be7e d2ae 1747  )...|..j.=.~...G
000000f0: d66b 2853 7b68 f87c 73b7 17bd 9784 e7dc  .k(S{h.|s.......
00000100: 6deb c9ed b633 cf4b df39 883f 2e4d caeb  m....3.K.9.?.M..
00000110: d977 8f1a 17b3 bcba 8fa6 ae2f 1f8d aeb9  .w........./....
00000120: 90da e3d7 96a6 d2bc a43d 7f29 ea41 93a6  .........=.).A..
00000130: 5ccd dd07 d3d6 67dc 7d29 fe7e 55dd 8f59  \.....g.}).~U..Y
00000140: 9ebe 3e7c 359e b5cc 456c bb76 3d6d a9da  ..>|5...El.v=m..
00000150: 467c fd40 33c7 15ae af2d a90c 29ae cd86  F|.@3....-..)...
00000160: 64dc 86ef 78c2 65d4 bf53 1fbe b2fb ee57  d...x.e..S.....W
00000170: bad3 5865 daa0 5ac0 22dd ab5c 302d 5856  ..Xe..Z."..\0-XV
00000180: 65ee c405 bacf 69be 1fd0 8a2b 58b8 4077  e.....i....+X.@w
00000190: 442b bf19 98a8 ff82 690b 0683 f5b2 59ed  D+......i.....Y.
000001a0: 3ec3 b2c4 d9c0 826a 31bc e5f0 2dab 90b4  >......j1...-...
000001b0: eda4 63f3 ff6e 70c1 c489 03d5 cfd1 7a4b  ..c..np.......zK
000001c0: ac53 0fd5 f5d9 a7b7 ce2d fee3 9b5b 2d4b  .S.......-...[-K
000001d0: 9cb9 f516 ae6f b71f 778c beb2 fbd7 ad6c  .....o..w......l
000001e0: 3fb6 1cd5 b226 b593 e8fe b2ac db2c 4e7d  ?....&.......,N}
000001f0: 0efa b7d8 b86e f32d b7bf 7e5d ab3d 9790  .....n.-..~].=..
00000200: 58c6 c875 9074 8e26 26b4 83e4 7a48 3eae  X..u.t.&&...zH>.
00000210: a4f6 55b6 3693 b62e 93ae 031f f91d 6786  ..U.6.........g.
00000220: fbde b441 671b 51ab 2d6b e376 d74c 19ea  ...Ag.Q.-k.v.L..
00000230: 97c5 b585 5cee a719 8e37 b93d 63d1 73e9  ....\....7.=c.s.
00000240: 1c4b ac25 972f db35 94ad 2d27 9d3f f739  .K.%./.5..-'.?.9
00000250: 125f 97e1 fedc f593 db6d 9bcf 6fec 3918  ._.......m..o.9.
00000260: 5830 505d 5ebb 8dd6 aee7 c105 8331 cbcd  X0P]^........1..
00000270: 3e32 b437 1f49 e7ac 62f1 e7a8 f1ba 515a  >2.7.I..b.....QZ
00000280: bb3e 13eb 2143 b91a df07 5bbb cec2 edbb  .>..!C....[.....
00000290: ebb8 e573 cf4b b4cd a7af 0fb6 9d7c 3d63  ...s.K.......|=c
000002a0: f1e5 847c b79d 77db 80ac e722 5b19 d25e  ...|..w...."[..^
000002b0: 9bf1 e5cb b20d 883b 9efa fb87 bf1d 5508  .......;......U.
000002c0: cf5b f85d 8da8 aa2f 54a3 9b81 efa0 b323  .[.].../T......#
000002d0: f7a0 e396 3b05 f637 8cfa fdd6 9f30 5f39  ....;..7.....0_9
000002e0: fc95 ef3f d914 83ca 7797 65f9 bdb3 ae5b  ...?....w.e....[
000002f0: 58e7 c4d5 d79d 87ea fae1 4d20 6c14 d1ce  X.........M l...
00000300: 9abf 7c6e 23aa d9a7 dbe8 1a14 26ae 8e7c  ..|n#.......&..|
00000310: c495 2fb6 1c86 f80b 3cfc 9ddd 7796 755b  ../.....<...w.u[
```

EDIT2:
This is also happening while requesting the image over insecure HTTP with another client (code below). The first chunk (until the PNG header) is fine but if I keep doing recv I only receive garbage.

Other strange thing is that no matter the buffer size the first recv always retrieve only the PNG header.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>

#define MAXDATASIZE 100000


void *get_in_addr(struct sockaddr *sa){
    if (sa->sa_family == AF_INET) {
        return &(((struct sockaddr_in*)sa)->sin_addr);
    }

    return &(((struct sockaddr_in6*)sa)->sin6_addr);
}

int http_get(char *host, char *port, char *msg) {
    int sockfd, numbytes;
    char buf[MAXDATASIZE];
    struct addrinfo hints, *servinfo, *p;
    int rv;
    char s[INET6_ADDRSTRLEN];

    memset(&hints, 0, sizeof(hints));
    hints.ai_family = AF_UNSPEC;
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;

    if ((rv = getaddrinfo(host, port, &hints, &servinfo)) != 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "getaddrinfo: %s\n", gai_strerror(rv));
        return 1;
    }

    for (p=servinfo; p!=NULL; p=p->ai_next){
        if ((sockfd = socket(p->ai_family, p->ai_socktype, p->ai_protocol)) == -1) {
            perror("client: socket");
            continue;
        }

        if (connect(sockfd, p->ai_addr, p->ai_addrlen) == -1) {
            close(sockfd);
            perror("client: connect");
            continue;
        }

        break;
    }

    if (p == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "client: failed to connect\n");
        return 2;
    }

    // convert the IP to string
    inet_ntop(p->ai_family, get_in_addr((struct sockaddr *)p->ai_addr), s, sizeof(s));
    printf("client: connecting to %s\n", s);

    freeaddrinfo(servinfo);

    // send
    if (send(sockfd, msg, strlen(msg), 0) == -1) {
        perror("send"); 
        exit(1);
    }

    // recv
    if ((numbytes = recv(sockfd, buf, MAXDATASIZE-1, 0)) == -1) {
        perror("recv");
        exit(1);
    }
    buf[numbytes] = '\0';

    printf("%s\n", buf);
    printf("%d\n", numbytes);

    close(sockfd);

    return 0;
}

int main() {
    http_get("host", "80", "GET /image.png  HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: host:80\r\n\r\n");
}
```

Comment: I am not strictly speaking answering your question, but fot the very same use case I use a cURL wrapper to fetch an image and save it.

Comment: Probably, payload is gzipped in http answer?

Comment: Not sure if I correctly understood you, but if you are removing the header info of the file, the rest will be not meaningful. Also `malloc(chunksize * sizeof(char))`, why not reserving extra byte for the null terminating character.

Comment: You have to parse the http response (a table will do). In this case, the last field of the table (let's call it the contente field) must have the 88746 bytes after the two \r\n from the HTTP response.

Comment: @MarcBalmer yeah, but I wanted to try to do a client just with openssl.

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff is there a way to tell the webserver to send the info uncompressed?

Comment: @macroland I need to remove the http header in order to store the image

Comment: @LuizMenezes I remove the header before saving the image. Is it that what you say I should do?

Comment: @jijigogo I noticed now that the contents are somehow diferent. Can you edit your question and post the binary file contents in hex mode, both from the browser and from your program for us to be sure?

Comment: @LuizMenezes edited!

Comment: First 8 bytes are correct PNG beginning - it's not gzipped. If file size is correct then there may be some decryption error.

Comment: @FareakyGnome the size is exactly the half of the one downloaded with the browser. :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally!

The reason I was getting garbage after the header was because I was using functions for NULL terminated strings on the image data (I guess that's why text responses were display just fine).

Instead of using strncat I made a concatenation function that uses a fixed size to concatenate the strings.

```
static char* concat(const char *dest, const char *src, size_t dest_size, size_t src_size) {
    char *new = (char *) malloc(dest_size + src_size);

    if (!dest && !src) return NULL;

    if (!new) return NULL;

    if (!dest) for (int i=0; i < src_size; i++) new[i] = src[i];
    else if (!src) for (int i=0; i < dest_size; i++) new[i] = dest[i];
    else {
        for (int i=0; i< dest_size; i++) new[i] = dest[i];
        for (int i=dest_size, j=0; j < src_size ; i++, j++) new[i] = src[j];
    }

    return new;
}
```

Then to push the not NULL terminated string to the Lua stack I need to use lua_pushlstring instead of lua_pushstring, specifying the total size of the data received.

[Here](http://pastebin.com/HeSka3a5) is the full code.

Thanks! :)